# How do I translate a numpy array to polyphonic music?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, audio, scipy

I want to use an array to play music/sounds. The output music/sounds needs to be polyphonic.

I tried this:

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import write
import numpy as np

duration=0.24
amp=1E4
rate=44100

def note(freq, duration, amp, rate):
    t = np.linspace(0, duration, duration * rate)
    data = np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t)*amp
    return data.astype(np.int16) # two byte integers

tone0 = note(0, duration, amp, rate) #silence
tone1 = note(261.63, duration, amp, rate) # C4
tone2 = note(329.63, duration, amp, rate) # E4
tone3 = note(392.00, duration, amp, rate) # G4


seq1 = np.concatenate((tone1,tone0,tone0,tone0, tone1),axis=1)
seq2 = np.concatenate((tone0,tone2,tone0,tone0, tone2),axis=1)
seq3 = np.concatenate((tone0,tone0,tone3,tone0, tone3),axis=1)

song = np.dstack((seq1,seq2,seq3))

write('song.wav', 44100, song)
```

I would like to play the song.wav file and hear the notes C, E and G one after the other then a silence and then the C chord (C,E,G notes play at the same time).

What I get, instead is an error by the write function. And that's ok because the write function (as far as I know it can´t create polyphonic wav files).

Just in case, the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "music2.py", line 26, in <module>
    write('song.wav', 44100, song)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/io/wavfile.py", line 168, in write
    fid.write(struct.pack('<ihHIIHH', 16, 1, noc, rate, sbytes, ba, bits))
struct.error: 'I' format requires 0 <= number <= 4294967295
```

1. Do you know an alternative to the write function that support polyphony?
2. I am open to a complete alternative of my code. The important point is to generate (or play) polyphonic sounds from a numpy array. I am trying to do something like this: http://img44.imageshack.us/img44/6182/music.swf, but much simpler; not GUI; not interactive, just the same idea of a 1 and 0 array were the row have assigned and specific sound/note and the columns code for the time those notes are played.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're getting is due to `write` wanting only a 1- or 2-dimensional array. You are passing it a 3-dimensional array (the output of `dstack` is 3D).

I'm not sure I get what you mean by polyphonic, but if you simply mean that you want to have different tones overlaid on each-other then all you need to do is superimpose the waveforms:

```
song = seq1 + seq2 + seq3 # Assumes seqs are of same length
```

In the end you probably want to be passing a 1-D array. 2-D arrays are for if you want to write stereo sounds.

Comment: Hi Isaac,
Thanks for noting that dstack returns a 3D array. I need a 2D array. 
Polyphonic means different sounds/frequencies sounding at the same time. I think I can´t just simple sum the "seq*" array, because instead of a chord I will get noise. In fact I try your solution and it is ok for the isolates notes but instead of a C chord I get an awful sound.

Comment: I just tried it myself and it seems to work as it should: three tones in sequence and then all together. I am using precisely your code, but with my '`song = `' line substituted for yours.

Comment: Yes, it work as expected, except than when all the sound play together the sound is like noise. Do you hear something "nice"?... let me check if the selected frequencies are ok.

Comment: Sorry Isaac you are right! I have changed the amplitude by mistake. Your solution is the correct one. Now I have to see how to eliminated the "click" sound at the end of each note. Thanks a lot!

Comment: To get rid of the 'click' you should make sure the waveform returns to zero at the end of the note (to prevent ringing in the speakers). For higher frequency sounds you should smoothly taper the amplitude to zero at the end of the tone.

Comment: Building the sum is physically correct here because acoustics is a linear theory. This means that the sum of two solutions of the wave equation, say a "C-note wave" and a "E-note wave", are again a solution to the wave equation. This means that different waves do not disturb each other as they propagate.

Comment: @aloctavodia Have you found a way to remove the 'click'? I do not see how to conserve the same rate and still be able to change the frequency.